# add space between image and p HTML elements

Tags: html, css, styling

How can I insert a few pixels of space between the image and p tags here. I wanted the p to the right of my image, but now its too close. I'd like to get a few pixels of space in.

HTML

```
<label class="radio-inline">
<input ng-change="" ng-model="" type="radio" value="f" id="inlineRadio1" name=""><img src="http://blahblah.png" alt="some_text"></img><p>Blah</p>
```

CSS

```
.radio-inline img{
    float: left;
}

.radio-inline p {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.radio-inline img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 16px 16px 0;
}
.radio-inline p {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input ng-change="" ng-model="" type="radio" value="f" id="inlineRadio1" name="">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-30-30-9.jpg" alt="some_text">
  <p>Blah</p>
</label>
```

Comment: thanks, I'm no CSS pro. I tried adding a single margin-left or margin-right, but neither worked.